# How to control redirection operator passed as one of the arguments to a bash function?

Tags: bash, function, parameter-passing, io-redirection

I'm trying to script some long/repetitive configuration & build operations in bash.
Started with a function that displays given command plus args and then executes it with given args.
Function definition follows:

```
runit () {
    cmd=${@}
    echo "${cmd}"
    ${cmd}
}

runit touch /tmp/cltconf1
```

Above (not involving redirection operator) displays the command and touches the target file as expected.

```
runit echo "gEnableSecureClient=True" > clt1.conf
```

Above (involving redirection operator) doesn't display command before execution and the content of clt1.conf file after the execution is:

```
echo gEnableSecureClient=True
gEnableSecureClient=True
```

I could understand that the redirection is not being controlled and thus causing the echo `${cmd}` to actually write content `echo gEnableSecureClient=True` to clt1.conf and then actual command execution then writes content `gEnableSecureClient=True`.

I want to find out if this redirection operator can be controlled for my requirement.
Any shopts or escape sequence handling would help.

Comment: Storing commands as strings (or passing them as arguments) doesn't always work very well; see [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is:

> How to control redirection operator passed as one of the arguments to a bash function?

Invent your own invention and use it to pass the context (filename to be redirected to) to your function.  You could  use a global variable or you could use positional arguments with some rarely used argument style, like for example `++`, for example:

```
runit() {
   # parse arguments - detect `++` followed by `>` and filename
   local cmd
   while (($#)); do
      case "$1" in
      "++") break; ;;
      *) cmd+=("$1"); ;;
      esac
      shift
   done
   local outf=/dev/stdout
   if (($#)) && [[ "$1" == "++" ]]; then
      shift
      while (($#)); do
         case "$1" in
         ">") outf=$2; shift; ;;
         *) echo "ERROR: Invalid arguments: expected >" >&2; return 1; ;;
         esac
         shift
      done
   fi
   if (($#)); then
        echo "ERROR: internal error when parsing arguments" >&2; return 1
   fi

   echo "Running ${cmd[*]} > $outf"
   "${cmd[@]}" > "$outf"
}
   
runit echo "gEnableSecureClient=True" ++ '>' clt1.conf
```

or example with global var, way simpler, but more spagetti:

```
runit() {
   if [[ -n "${runit_outf:-}" ]]; then     
       echo "$* > $runit_outf" 
       "$@" > "$runit_outf"
       runit_outf=  # let's clear it after use
   else
       echo "$*"
       "$@"
   fi
}

# outputs to stdout
runit echo 123     

runit_outf=clt1.conf  # spaghetti code
runit echo 123        # outputs to file
```

This is just a template code that I did not test and have written in StackOverflow. It will not handle file descriptors - for that, you could write your own logic that would either parse the expression - ie. detect `&` in `>&1`, or write very unsafe code and call `eval`.

The presented above way is **not** recommended in any way, rather I wouldn't ever write code like that and would strongly discourage writing such complicated logic to handle simple cases. Instead, you should differentiate the output of a command from the logging stream of command, typically you would:

```
runit() {
    local cmd
    cmd=("$@")
    echo "${cmd[*]}" >&2
    "${cmd[@]}"
}
```

or use a dedicated beforehand-opened file descriptor in your code or redirect output to `/dev/tty` depending on the situation.

Before continuing further, you should definitely research what are and when to use bash arrays, research word splitting, and filename expansion, and check your script with https://shellcheck.net . Your function as it is now will break in surprisingly many ways when passing arguments with spaces and with special characters like `*` or `?`.

Comment: U've given a lot of new information regarding Bash scripting. Kudos for the shellcheck.net link. Thank you.